# Send email when a portfolio project is updated

Tags: plugins, email

I am trying to automatically inform specific registered users when the content of a project in the portfolio changes. It's like automatic newsletters on blog changes but I need it for a portfolio and only for a specific project.

Is this possible to achieve? I guess I will need a plugin. So far I use MailPoet but I couldn't find such an option there. Neither in Subscribe2.
Can anybody give me a hint how to send portfolio project changes?

Comment: Plugin is not necessary, I think. You can use WP filters and action to "catch" event of updating (saving) post and then send message to some users... but it all depends on how your application works. What is "portfolio"? Custom post type? What is that one project? What users should be noticed? Etc.

Comment: Thank you. Portfolio is a custom post type from the theme Ikebana. A project is a part of the portfolio. So far I understand you, you recommend to catch the update event (programmatically) and send emails to the specific users (programmatically). Is this right? Is there a solution to handle such events without coding?

Comment: I don't think there is ideal solution/plugin for you. You can find code inspiration [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19040/alert-email-when-any-post-or-page-is-changed).

Comment: You could take a look at the Edit Flow plugin. It does a lot more than you need, but does include notifications functionality.

Comment: The Plugin notifies when creating projects (which is great) but not when one is updated. Thank you though.