# E-Mail Notification on post edit

Tags: email, notifications

I've been looking for a way to notify users when a post has been edited.
I've tried the following plugins:

- Better Notifications for WordPress
- Post Status Notifier
- Digest Notifications

(These were tried to generate E-Mails after posts been edited)

- Edit Flow
- PublishPress

(These were used to create custom status for posts under edit)

In the best case, I want to notify all colleagues that a post has been edited 24h after a post hasn't been edited.

Currently, I'm trying **digest notification** to notify all colleagues every day with the edited posts. The setup hasn't worked out so far.

Comment: I'm not seeing a question here. Have you worked with any of the plugin developers to see if they can help with your concerns?

Comment: I've contacted most of the developers, but only two started to respond without going into the issue itself.

Answer (score 0):

i think this should help,

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95512/139936

on 'save_post' hook, you can send your email. 
But it will only work on direct update.

if you want to wait 24h, you will have to set a cron job that will check every post & send an email with posts updated in the last XX hours.